# Expose page alias in wagtail API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Wagtail recently gained support for page aliases (the same page in another part of the tree).

The API returns these pages as if they are "normal" pages.

I'd like the API to tell me that the page is an alias of another page. The reason for this is to be able to add a `rel="canonical"` link.

I'd also like to be able to (optionally) return the list of aliases for the original page using the API. This way I can build a list of "this page is also available here".

It seems that it is possible to detect an aliases by inspecting the `alias_of` `ForeignKey`:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c5f49274c8730ce04ca76df1ceef96d5cc83fac0/wagtail/core/models.py#L843

But I'm unsure on how to make this work with the Wagtail API and DRF serializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up just adding a serializer and added it to our `Page` base class:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from wagtail.api import APIField
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class AliasPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('id', 'full_url')

class BasePage(Page):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    api_meta_fields = [
        APIField('alias_of', serializer=AliasPageSerializer()),
    ]
```

In the API response this results in something like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1337,
    "meta": {
        ...
        "alias_of": {
            "id": 42,
            "full_url": "https://example.com/blog/example-blog/"
        },
        ...
    },
    "title": "Example blog",
    ...
}
```